# Cursor = Cursors.None for popup in code

Tags: c#, wpf

Im trying to set the cursor to none in code for a popup but I cant get it to work. The cursor is still shown when it is over the popup. What am I doing wrong?

```
public void SubWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {

     if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
     {
         TextBlock popupText = new TextBlock();
         popupText.Text = "Complete" ;
         popupText.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
         popupText.Foreground = Brushes.White;          
         popupText.Width = 130;
         popupText.FontSize = 30;
         popupText.IsHitTestVisible = false;
         popupText.Cursor = Cursors.None;

         Popup Popup = new Popup();
         Popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
         Popup.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(1086, 16, 0, 0);
         Popup.IsHitTestVisible = false;
         Popup.Cursor = Cursors.None;

         Popup_Text.Child = popupText;
         Popup.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Comment: What is `Popup_Text`? Why you create a `Popup` but then you add the `TextBlock` to another control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the `IsHitTestVisible` property of the `TextBlock` to `false`:

```
TextBlock popupText = new TextBlock();
popupText.Text = "Complete";
popupText.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
popupText.Foreground = Brushes.White;
popupText.Width = 130;
popupText.Height = 130;
popupText.FontSize = 30;
//popupText.IsHitTestVisible = false;
popupText.Cursor = Cursors.None;

Popup Popup = new Popup();
//Popup.AllowsTransparency = true;
Popup.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(1086, 16, 0, 0);
Popup.IsHitTestVisible = false;
Popup.Cursor = Cursors.None;

Popup.Child = popupText;
Popup.IsOpen = true;
```

Also note that your app can only change the cursor when the cursor is actually over one of your app's elements. The "background" of a transparent `Popup` does not belong to your application so `Cursors.None` will only apply when you move the mouse pointer over the actual text in the `TextBlock`.